# Get active excel workbook object in javascript

Tags: javascript, excel

Currently the code I am running is:

```
var excel = new ActiveXObject("Excel.Application");
var excel_file = excel.Workbooks.Open("filepath");
var excelsheet = excel_file.ActiveSheet;
var noofsubs = excelsheet.Cells(24,3).Value;
```

excel.workbboks.open commands opens an excel file. But how do I get reference to the already open excel file? maybe like

```
var excel_file = excel.ActiveWorkbooks.Activate("excelfilename");
```

Answer (score 1):

Typically you'd use `GetObject()` if there's already an instance of Excel running and you want to get a reference to that. Note though that if there are >1 instance running, the one you get back can't be controlled from your script.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/7tf9xwsc%28v=vs.94%29.aspx

```
var XL;

try 
{ 
   // Existing instance running ? 
   XL = GetObject("", "Excel.Application"); 
} 
catch(e) 
{ 
   // Excel wasn't running: start new instance 
   XL = new ActiveXObject("Excel.Application"); 
}
```

Comment: if there are more than 1 workbooks open, how can I decide which one to make active? do we have any 'name' property to this object? something like            XL(0).name;

Comment: If there are more than one workbook open then typically you'd use something like `XL.Workbooks("Nameofworkbook").Activate`